# Проблемы с выводом цветов в консоль

Tags: python

У меня на python установлен модуль colorama 0.4.3, а сам python версии 3.8.3. Windows 10 Pro. У меня редактор кода VS Code. При создании программ с использованием библиотеки colorama в VS Code все цвета прекрасно отображаются, а в консоли (кстати я также пробовал в cmder, такая же проблема):

[image: Фото из cmder]

[image: Фото из консоли]

[image: Фото из VS Code]

Где-то слышал, что нужно установить переменную FORCE_COLOR со значением TRUE, но это не помогает. Что нужно сделать, чтобы в консоли появились нормальные цвета?

Comment: Вы забыли вызвать функцию `colorama.init()`

Comment: @andreymal. А для чего это? Если вызываю в начале, то вылетает ошибка, что модуль colorama не найдем, а если в конце, то все работает так же

Comment: Вам действительно надо вызвать colorama.init(), но т.к Вы его импортировали "from colorama import init <..>" просто после Import'a вызовите init()

Comment: @CodeIsmylife. Хорошо ,спасибо. Я вызвал init() и в консоли все заработало, правда, немного "коряво". Но все равно огромное спасибо!